# Hadoop: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused when running start-dfs.sh

Tags: hadoop

When starting the latest (Okt 2014) Hadoop with `start-dfs.sh` we are seeing:

> connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused when running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Configure "HADOOP_SSH_OPTS" in your hadoop-env.sh, to add any SSH CLI
>   options you need to always be present when the Hadoop scripts use SSH.
>   A line like 'export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p "' perhaps would be what
>   you are looking for.

Source: Interweb

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 8):

Install `openssh` server.

For Ubuntu command is :

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

In hadoop-env.sh file ( present in /etc/hadoop) add the following line :

```
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p 22"
```

Answer (score 1):

Install and start `openssh` server. Here is the command for CentOS:

Install Open SSH server:

```
sudo yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients
```

Start SSH server:

```
sudo service sshd start
```

Answer (score 0):

### OS

On Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

### Install OpenSSH

`sudo apt install openssh-server openssh-client -y`

### Start SSH

`sudo service ssh start`